# Kivy widget position not stable as new widgets added

Tags: python, kivy

I have a very simple Kivy project where I want to ask the user to input a number and then have the app display some calculations. I start out with the following, which puts the widgets at the top of the screen just as I expect:

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.main = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.my_number = '100000'
        inp_box = BoxLayout(pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                            size_hint=(0.4, 0.2))
        inp_box.add_widget(Label(text='Enter something', 
                        pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                        size_hint=(None, None),
                        size=(300,50),
                        font_size=25))
        self.get_inp = TextInput(text=self.my_number, 
                        multiline=False, 
                        pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                        size_hint=(None, None),
                        size=(125,50),
                        font_size=25)
        go = Button(text='Button',
                    pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                        size_hint=(None, None),
                        size=(100,50),
                        font_size=25)
        go.bind(on_release=self.more_widgets)
        inp_box.add_widget(self.get_inp)
        inp_box.add_widget(go)
        self.main.add_widget(inp_box)
```

All good so far. All widgets appear at the top of the screen as expected.

However if I add another `BoxLayout` under this one, it appears toward the middle of the screen vertically. Based on my understanding of `pos_hint` it should be right under the `inp_box` widget and sized to 20% of the vertical space on screen.

```
lbl_box = BoxLayout(pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                            size_hint=(0.4, 0.2))
        for i in ['One', 'Two', 'Three']:
            lbl_box.add_widget(Label(text=i, 
                            size_hint=(None, None),
                            size=(100,50),
                            pos_hint={'x': 0.2, 'top': 1},
                            font_size=20))
        self.main.add_widget(lbl_box)
```

Lastly, I want the app to do some calculations and display the results. When this displays it pushes up the `lbl_box' widget toward the` inp_box` widget. I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
    def more_widgets(self, instance):
        self.my_number = self.get_inp.text      
        number_disp = GridLayout(cols=4,
                            pos_hint={'x': 0.1, 'top': 0.5},
                            size_hint=(0.8, 0.6))
        for t in range(0, 20):
            n = int(self.my_number) + t
            number_disp.add_widget(
                        Label(text=f'{t}: {n:,.0f}'))
        self.main.add_widget(number_disp)
```

Full MRE below:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.main = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.my_number = '100000'
        inp_box = BoxLayout(pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                            size_hint=(0.4, 0.2))
        inp_box.add_widget(Label(text='Enter something', 
                        pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                        size_hint=(None, None),
                        size=(300,50),
                        font_size=25))
        self.get_inp = TextInput(text=self.my_number, 
                        multiline=False, 
                        pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                        size_hint=(None, None),
                        size=(125,50),
                        font_size=25)
        go = Button(text='Button',
                    pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                        size_hint=(None, None),
                        size=(100,50),
                        font_size=25)
        go.bind(on_release=self.more_widgets)
        inp_box.add_widget(self.get_inp)
        inp_box.add_widget(go)
        self.main.add_widget(inp_box)
        
        lbl_box = BoxLayout(pos_hint={'x': 0, 'top': 1},
                            size_hint=(0.4, 0.2))
        for i in ['One', 'Two', 'Three']:
            lbl_box.add_widget(Label(text=i, 
                            size_hint=(None, None),
                            size=(100,50),
                            pos_hint={'x': 0.2, 'top': 1},
                            font_size=20))
        self.main.add_widget(lbl_box)
        
        return self.main
    
    def more_widgets(self, instance):
        self.my_number = self.get_inp.text      
        number_disp = GridLayout(cols=4,
                            pos_hint={'x': 0.1, 'top': 0.5},
                            size_hint=(0.8, 0.6))
        for t in range(0, 20):
            n = int(self.my_number) + t
            number_disp.add_widget(
                        Label(text=f'{t}: {n:,.0f}'))
        self.main.add_widget(number_disp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way `size_hint` works in a `BoxLayout`, see the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html). From that documentation:

> The size_hint uses the available space after subtracting all the
> fixed-size widgets. For example, if you have a layout that is 800px
> wide, and add three buttons like this:
>
> btn1 = Button(text='Hello', size=(200, 100), size_hint=(None, None))
>
> btn2 = Button(text='Kivy', size_hint=(.5, 1)
>
> btn3 = Button(text='World', size_hint=(.5, 1))
>
> The first button will be 200px wide as specified, the second and third
> will be 300px each, e.g. (800-200) * 0.5

Since both your internal `BoxLayouts` have a `size_hint_y` of `0.2`, they actually share equally in the vertical space that the `self.main` `BoxLayout` has available. If you specify different `size_hint_y` values for the internal `BoxLayouts`, they will get vertical space that is proportional to those `size_hint_y` values.

Comment: Thanks but I had read the docs. Changing the size parameters around the `BoxLayout` doesn't fix the problem of the widgets moving when new widgets are created. At least, in all the combinations I could think of to try.